# Records vs Single-Case Discriminated Unions

Tags: f#, record, discriminated-union

What are the Pro's and Con's of using either

```
type Complex = 
    { 
        real: float; 
        imag: float;
    }
```

or

```
type Complex = 
    Complex of 
        real: float * 
        imag: float
```

I am particularly interested in readability and handling in different situations.
And to a lesser extent, performance.

Comment: On F#4.1 for performance you might consider adding `[<Struct>]`

Comment: As we are talking about Complex numbers DUs bring the benefit that DU can have two cases `Rectangular` and `Polar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using helper functions you could get the same out of both approaches.

**Record**

```
type ComplexRec = 
    { 
        real: float 
        imag: float
    }

// Conciseness
let buildRec(r,i) =
    { real = r ; imag = i }

let c = buildRec(1.,5.)

// Built-in field acces
c.imag
```

**Union type**

```
type ComplexUnion = 
    Complex of 
        real: float * imag: float

// Built-in conciseness
let c = Complex(1.,5.)

// Get field - Could be implemented as members for a more OO feel
let getImag = function
    Complex(_,i) -> i

getImag c
```

I imagine the (frequent) decomposition of the union type could influence performance, but I'm no expert on the subject.

Comment: Neat! So essentially you're saying:
DU: easy to compose but "hard" to decompose.  
rec: "hard" to compose but easy to decompose  
(without resorting to helper funcs)

Answer (score 3):

In case of the record type, let's say that you declared symbol `it : Complex` you have immediate access to both fields like: `it.real, it.imag`

In the case of discriminated union (DU) you have to first unpack DU type like:

```
match it with
| Complex (real, imag) -> real, imag
```

DU  makes sense when you have some choices on the type. Your Complex type doesn't branch to few cases, it only has one possible shape, case.

In this case I'm in favour of record type as it gives more readable code in usage.

Comment: Note that for single case union you don't need `match` to unpack it.